# Should application double check if data was acted upon?

Tags: database, crud

Assuming the context of a CRUD:

After performing a database `DELETE`, should an application's deletion method check if the records were actually removed from the database?

If so, how valid is it for the other "altering" actions (CU)?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Alternatively, by ‘soft deleting’ a record you defer the problem of actually deleting, and handling failed deletes.

Comment: `Alternatively, by ‘soft deleting’ a record you defer the problem of actually deleting,` then you have to validate whether the soft delete has been performed properly. You are at the very same point. Not a big deal.

Comment: @gnat Thank you. It is a very generic question. The answers actually show the simple and accurate solution. I *was* going way off of the obvious correct technique in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Most relational database systems will return the "number of records affected," which in the case of a DELETE, would be the number of records deleted.  That's all the confirmation you need.

Answer (score 2):

It is standard for delete sql statements to return the number of impacted statements, or in other words, the number of deleted lines.

You're free to do with that information what you will.  If it is relevant to your client to know that the delete was a success, the server would respond accordingly.  If it wasn't but it is transparent to the user (usually best, unless it is important to know if and when another user deletes that record first), then you would disregard and return a success anyway.

My idea is that errors of this type where you didn't delete anything get reported to a log for a systems administrator, but are reported as a success to the user.  In most cases the user doesn't need to see errors unless they don't obtain the result they desire and further action is required, at least in my humble opinion.